# Asp .net core - send parameters using Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

during code writing I encountered a problem which I do not know how to solve.
I need to send some parameters into Index using Html.ActionLink but if I use this type of code i send only "Name" and "true" but ***no parameters*** from Model.state:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", "Home", new { Model.state, sortBy = "Name", isNameSortedDescending = true })
```

However, if I use this kind of code I send Model.state (3 x true) without "Name" and "true":

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", "Home",  Model.state, new { sortBy = "Name", isNameSortedDescending = true })
```

Does someone know how to send all of this parameters?

Comment: Can you please share with us your HomeController's Index action signature?

Answer (score 1):

ActionLink has several overloads.

Your first attempt matches to the following overload:

- **linkText**: Name
- **actionName**: Index
- **controllerName**: Home
- **routeValues**: `new { Model.state, sortBy = "Name", isNameSortedDescending = true }`

Your second attempt matches to the following overload:

- **linkText**: Name
- **actionName**: Index
- **controllerName**: Home
- **routeValues**: `Model.State`
- **htmlAttributes**: `new { sortBy = "Name", isNameSortedDescending = true }`

You would need to use the first one to pass (only) routing data.